# regular exp. 2 chars and 5 digits or just 5 digits

Tags: regex

I need to use a reg. exp for validation of input field.
Valid input is: 2 characters and 5 digits or only 5 digits.

I've tried with following reg exp:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}.*[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5})$
```

But this allows me to type ex. : aaa12345

It seems like this expression is at least 2 characters (optional) and 5 digits. Where am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The order is always 2 characters (optional) and then 5 digits (ex. aa12345)

Comment: issue is with `.*` = any character any number of times

Comment: Do the characters and digits occur in any special order? I. e., is `A1B2345` valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `.*` in the middle of the first expression:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5})$
```

Comment: Why not simply `^([a-zA-Z]{2})?[0-9]{5}$`?

Comment: @georg Good idea. I wanted my solution to be as close as possible to the OP. The only drawback that your solution has is, that you can't reference the whole match in a single group anymore.

Comment: @SebastianStigler: Yes you can - it's the entire match (`$0` or `$&` or whatever the regex flavor uses for this)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ok, but never the less you have to change this reference anywhere in your code while my solution doesn't need any code changes other than the regexp itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:(?:\d{5})|((?!(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]){3})[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}))$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/31

This will enable you to

```
1)Enter 5 digits

2)Enter 5 digits and 2 characters in any order.The `lookahead` makes sure that the characters are not more than `2`.
```

Comment: This will allow `a12a345` which doesn't look like what the OP wanted.